# How to work with more than one browser tab in a Coded Ui Test

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

During one of my tests (using Coded UI), a new tab is launched, and in order to make my test flows properly, i have to close this tab. Does anyone know how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

New tabs in IE are of WinTabPage type (WinForms control).
you should first locate it. some thing like:

```
var tab = new WinTabPage(parent);

        tab.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "New tab's name");

        var CloseButton = new WinButton(tab);
        CloseButton .SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Close Button Name");

        Mouse.Click(CloseButton);
```

where the parent is a BrowserWindow.

this should do the trick.